# iframe scroll to top onsubmit

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I want to scroll to the top of the parent page once a form in an iframe has submitted. I've tried many different ways to do this including adding onload to the iframe tag itself and with jQuery/JS, none have worked so far, now I'm trying:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    <!-- BEGIN HIDING
        window.onload = pageScroll; function pageScroll() {
            window.scrollTo(0, top);
            scrolldelay = setTimeout('pageScroll()', 200);
        }
    // DONE HIDING-->
   </script>
```

Test page is here: http://www.moneycorp.com/uk/personal/General-Enquiry2/

Any ideas why this doesn't work? Thanks.

Comment: I see this in iframe tag - <iframe frameborder="0" height="875" width="1000" src="http://dev-vdciis16/PartnerWidget/contactusmcprivate/"></iframe> and it actually doesn't load

Comment: The iframe doesn't load for you?

Comment: nope, it'f some your local development address I guess - http://dev-vdciis16/PartnerWidget/contactusmcprivate/